# BIT column from SQL source converted to Boolean by data collector

Tags: sql, sqldatatypes, streamsets

I'm pulling data from SQL server which has a bit Datatype Column having values 0 & 1.We are using Streamsets to load the data from sql into databricks. What happens is 0 and 1 from Source server is getting converted to False and True while Loading into BOOLEAN column. Is there a way in Streamsets which will help me to get 1 and 0 in target and not Boolean value in Target.

Comment: Not sure I understand at what moment the column get converted.
Could you share the pipeline or the fragment where conversion takes place?

In theory in streamsets you could use the FieldType converter processor to set the type for the fields explicitly.

Comment: Hey Andrey, if i use the field type converter to convert bit data into string the streamsets omits those records and we missed out a lot of data.

Comment: But at what moment your data gets converted?

Comment: It gets converted after it passes through the field type converter and before loading into the destination.

Comment: What is the type of the record after you read int from source(bit field)?
Is it boolean?
Can you check it in preview mode?

Comment: SO is for programming questions only

Answer (score 0):

You can use expression evaluator to convert your boolean field to Long, or any other type.

Check my example pipeline below(fiels expression in particular):
[image]

Check the streamsets expression language for more examples:
https://docs.streamsets.com/portal/#datacollector/3.4.0/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Expression_Language/ExpressionLanguage_overview.html